# Is It Possible to Sign a tiff file using CoSign

Tags: cosign-api

We are trying to sign a Tiff file using CoSign but it is showing error: "File is not supported".

Is it possible to Sign a Tiff using CoSign via web-agent API or via back-end.
Or please suggest if any alternate is there.

Answer (score 1):

The CoSign Web Agent doesn't sign tiff files. It can be used to sign PDF, Word, and Excel files in their native formats. It can also automatically convert Word and Excel files to pdf format.

**Tiff files can be signed via CoSign in any of three ways:**

**CoSign Signature API**

[Docs](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.2/Default.htm#doc_7.2/Create%20and%20Sign.htm). This is a new API and there are some issues with the documentation. Please see other questions about this API and ask additional questions if you have a problem.

**CoSign Signature SOAP API**

[Docs](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.2/Default.htm#doc_7.2/CoSign%20Signature%20SOAP.htm) This API's Sign method can sign tiff files.

**CoSign Signature Local API**

[Docs](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.2/Default.htm#doc_7.2/CoSign%20Signature%20Local.htm) This is a Windows local API. It can also be used to sign tiff files.